# Copy data From one file to another file doesn't work (Batch Script)

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

First I read the path from another file and stored it into "c" variable 
But Path contains by "C" variable has space like  ~~~  E:\my folder\first.txt

When I try batch script to copy data from one file(file path specified by c variable) into another file, it doesn't work

```
COPY %c% E:\shubham\second.txt
```

I also tried with double quotes:

```
COPY "%c%" "E:\shubham\second.txt"
```

doesn't work

Here is the full Script:

```
@echo on SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%i in (E:\WritePath.txt) do set c=!content! %%i echo %c% COPY %c% E:\shubham\second.txt
```

Comment: please provide more information so that we can help u & u can get the help you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the variable correctly. it should be `set c=%%i`

but you do not need to set the variables here, you can use the metavariable as is.

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (E:\WritePath.txt) (
    Set var=!var! %%a
    echo !var!
)
echo !var! >>"E:\shubham\second.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you but, it also doesn't work, I am facing problem in spaces in the file path @GerhardBarbnard

Comment: @shubhamsuryawanshi please check now. It seems you wanted to concatenate the results and `echo` to another file?